# is tomcat in my fedora?

Tags: mysql, apache, tomcat, webserver, fedora

i am asked to implement jsp file and given instruction on how to set all mysql,tomcat and all.

i did follow everything however when i open `http://localhost` nothing happened. only error to connect page of the browser. i'm assuming my webserver is having a problem and still not up.

in the instruction, i was asked to run this command to check if it is up:

```
ps –ef | grep tomcat
```

and the example shows that im suppose to get something like this :

http://tinyurl.com/7yvmm9q

but i only got this:

```
root       2319 2297 0 15:58/0 00:00:00 tomcat
```

i dont get the rest of the lines as im supposed to get in the example given. what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'd firstly check if tomcat listens on 80 port. You can find this by typing `lsof -i` - here you will see if tomcat is listening  on any port.

Comment: i checked, but tomcat is not even in the list.

Comment: default port for tomacat is 8080

Comment: due to http://tinyurl.com/7yvmm9q you should have java listening 80 (8080) port, not tomcat.